# Bootbox : issue with bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I have installed bootbox with

```
bower install bootbox --save -dev
```

But when I use it I am getting

> angular.js:13294 Error: $.fn.modal is not defined; please double check
>   you have included the Bootstrap JavaScript library. See
>   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ for more details.

I do have **modal.js** in my project, installed with bower too.

**bower.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.2",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.2.5",
    "angular-cache-buster": "0.4.3",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.2",
    "ngstorage": "0.3.10",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.2",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "2.2.3",
    "jquery": "2.2.2",
    "json3": "3.3.2",
    "modernizr": "3.3.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "12.0.4",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.2.2",
    "swagger-ui": "2.1.4",
    "ng-table": "^0.8.3",
    "ng-contextmenu": "^0.4.1",
    "ui-select": "angular-ui-select#^0.16.1",
    "components-font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-contextmenu": "^0.9.7",
    "Ionicons": "ionicons#^2.0.1",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-switch": "^0.5.1",
    "jqcloud2": "^2.0.2",
    "angular-jqcloud": "^1.0.3",
    "ngWig": "ng-wig#^3.0.7",
    "AngularJS-Toaster": "angularjs-toaster#^2.1.0",
    "sockjs-client": "1.0.3",
    "stomp-websocket": "2.3.4",
    "typeahead.js": "^0.11.1",
    "bootbox.js": "bootbox#^4.4.0"
  }
```

[image]

Any idea of where can this problem come from?

Comment: Bootbox is not self-contained library. It builds on top of Bootstrap's modals, so , you need to load Bootstrap first

Comment: Did you resolve this